# Does anyone know of a front-end method that resolves urls similar to ASP.NET MVC Url.Action()

Tags: html, hyperlink, url-routing, relative-path, resolveurl

What I am looking for is a lightweight front-end framework that can take partials, such as a footer navigation, and resolve urls correctly from any location in the file system.

For example, I have a main index page with footer links that navigate to "foo/" but within the foo/index page I want similarly nested footer links to resolve to "../bar/"

I have previous experience in .NET ASP.NET where it's very handy to define a link with "~/" to get everything to route right.

I know I could get around this by providing full domain qualified links, but I was wondering if I could use relative links with a little help from a utility, technique or framework I am not aware of yet.